# Where is this material viewport in Blender 2.8 Beta?

Tags: 3d-view

Sorry, i'm just a noob in 3d program, so i don't really know what to call this thing.

[image]

[image]

But do you happen to know how to display this kind of material in Blender 2.8 Beta viewport?

Answer (score 1):

Too bad that you cropped your image so tight... The shading options you are looking for are to the right of the image you posted.
Move the cursor over to the right of the screen and click to make the options active.

[image]

Comment: Sorry i crop the image too tight. But i already know about that shading option on the right side. I always use it whenever i want to use that material. But recently i updated my Blender 2.8. and i can't find my favorite material anymore.

Comment: I think i found the problem. The material is still there in the updated version, it just turned into black & white.

Comment: That's depressing. I miss the old warm evening color.